# Sharepoint 2010 List Unable to Edit documents

Tags: permissions

We have a list in sp 2010 and members of a group with the following permissions:

- Limited Access (greyed out)
- ViewAddEdit

are not able to edit documents that they uploaded.

Here is a link to the screen shot of permissions https://i.stack.imgur.com/HePd0.jpg

Any help in resolving this will be much appreciated

Comment: you can also set permissions on the list itself... check the list permissions.

Comment: The list has permissions to allow the users of that group to edit lists. Inspite of that they are not able to update documents attached to a list.

Comment: what abilities does ViewAddEdit role have? have you checked the role definition?

Answer (score 1):

ViewAddEdit is not a standard permission level. Please, check the definiton of that permission level and you will see which privilege is missing.

Answer (score 0):

These are the group permissions towards the site. Try going in the List Settings > List Permissions in the Ribbon and adding the group there, the default "content" permissions in sharepoint are:

```
Read
Contribute
Full Control
Design
```

You may need to stop inherting permissions on the list, [more information here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/edit-permissions-for-a-list-library-or-individual-item-HA101805400.aspx)